# UE4 Как создавать свои анимации?

Tags: анимация, unreal-engine-4

Я гуглил, но нашел только как создавать анимационные блупринты. А мне надо именно сами анимации, например прыжок, бег, ходьба.

т.е. вот эти штуки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я навел мышкой на этот файл и увидел, что его тип Animation Sequence. В Add New такого типа нет...

Вообщем вопрос: Как создавать свои анимации и делать их. Например если есть возможность например видео как вы делаете анимацию махания рукой или тому подобное. Можно и текстом. Или ссылку, где это все рассказано, рад любому ответу!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю насколько актуально отвечать на вопрос ведь задан он был 3 месяца назад, но так или иначе.

Анимации создаются в различных программах например таких как Blender, Maya, 3ds max и тому подобных. После чего импортируются в Unreal Engine 4.

Вот первое видео которое выдал youtube:
[Создание анимации для персонажа Ue4 в Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnilMroO8D8)

Если есть какие-то проблемы с созданием своих анимаций то их можно покупать на различных площадках ну или использовать [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/).

Comment: К сожалению вопрос не актуален и не совсем корректен. Анимации можно создавать и в самом движке. Возможно в сторонних программах удобнее, но разницу я не ощутил)

Comment: @Данил, согласен. Совсем забыл про это :)~ Anyway хорошего дня.